# Why the `warning C4804: '>': unsafe use of type 'bool' in operation` is popping on Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, cl

#### Why the `warning C4804: '>': unsafe use of type 'bool' in operation` is popping on Visual Studio 2015?

If you run this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main( int argumentsCount, char* argumentsStringList[] )
{
#define COMPUTE_DEBUGGING_LEVEL_DEBUG      0
#define COMPUTE_DEBUGGING_DEBUG_INPUT_SIZE 32

    int inputLevelSize;
    int builtInLevelSize;

    inputLevelSize   = strlen( "a1" );
    builtInLevelSize = strlen( "a1 a2" );

    if( ( 2 > inputLevelSize > COMPUTE_DEBUGGING_DEBUG_INPUT_SIZE )
        || ( 2 > builtInLevelSize > COMPUTE_DEBUGGING_DEBUG_INPUT_SIZE ) )
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR while processing the DEBUG LEVEL: " << "a1" << std::endl;
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
}
```

You will get:

```
./cl_env.bat /I. /EHsc /Femain.exe main.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23506 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.cpp
main.cpp(52): warning C4804: '>': unsafe use of type 'bool' in operation
main.cpp(53): warning C4804: '>': unsafe use of type 'bool' in operation
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.23506.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:main.exe 
main.obj
```

Where `cl_env.bat` is:

```
@echo off

:: Path to your Visual Studio folder.
::
:: Examples:
::     C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0
::     F:\VisualStudio2015
set VISUAL_STUDIO_FOLDER=F:\VisualStudio2015

:: Load compilation environment
call "%VISUAL_STUDIO_FOLDER%\VC\vcvarsall.bat"

:: Invoke compiler with any options passed to this batch file
"%VISUAL_STUDIO_FOLDER%\VC\bin\cl.exe" %*
```

The lines in question are not bool:

```
    if( ( 2 > inputLevelSize > COMPUTE_DEBUGGING_DEBUG_INPUT_SIZE )
        || ( 2 > builtInLevelSize > COMPUTE_DEBUGGING_DEBUG_INPUT_SIZE ) )
```

How to correctly do expressions as `0 < x < 10`?

What do was said is relative to the interpreter. Examples:

1. When an C++ standard states the compiler must to understand `0 <  x < 10` as `( 0 < x ) && ( x < 10 )`, but the compiler is actually is understanding it as `( 0 < x ) < 10`, we call it a compilers bug.
2. Therefore when the user states the compiler must to understand `0 < x < 10` as `( 0 < x ) && ( x < 10 )`, but compiler is actually understanding it as `( 0 < x ) < 10`, we call it a user's bug.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Conditions like `a > b > c` do not work the way you think they do. In fact they work like `(a > b) > c` (since the `>` operator works left-to-right), but the result of `a > b` is a boolean, thus the warning.

The correct way would be to use `&&` (logical `and`):

```
if(a > b && b > c)
```

Comment: Do you mean, `<` is evaluated first than `&&` on the operator's precedence order, therefore the paren are redundant?

Comment: @addons_zz, yes, though one might argue that parenthesis may increase (or decrease) code readability. But yes, they are not mandatory.

Comment: @MSalters, you are right, I just think parenthesis improve readability of such conditions, but I completely understand that you might think that they actually reduce readability. I'll edit the answer nonetheless.

Answer (score 3):

If you compare it like `0 < x < 10` it first evaluates `0 < x` which is either true or false and then compare this to 10. You need to separate the expressions like `0 < x && x < 10`.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to write range check expressions is:

`( 0 < x ) && ( x < 10 )`

As written the line evaluates to `((0 < x) < 10)`.